# How can I add "smart" functionality to an old thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, rental, retrofit

I recently moved to an apartment, and my roommate and I were talking about how much better it would be if we had a smart thermostat. We're going to ask the landlord about an upgrade, but I thought I remembered seeing systems somewhere that allowed you to smart-ify a traditional thermostat *(very technical term, I know)*. It's one of the ones with just an up and a down button, nothing else.

Comment: It's easier to beg forgiveness than to ask permission, as they say. I'd change it out with a Nest (love mine--get a used/refurb 1st or 2nd gen cheap) and take it with you when you leave. There's very little risk of damage if you pay attention to the connection schedule.

Comment: What are the exact functions you want to achieve - e.g. just daily scheduling, or remote internet control, etc?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yeah mostly just scheduling; no sense in heating the apartment in the winter during the day when we're not there

Comment: as isherwood states Nest is nice, but make sure it is compatible with your system, there are a few that are not.  At least not directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices exist which are basically heaters with timers, which can be mounted under a traditional thermostat to bias it toward turning the heat off sooner. By juggling the two settings, this can be made to work somewhat like a setback thermostat.

Mostly obsolete, since not very efficient, but useful in cases where the owner forbids installing a real smart thermostat.

Comment: Sorta like faxing yourself a photocopy of an email, eh?

Comment: You can bias an old mercury thermostat by sticking a piece of cardboard in the bimetallic coil...

Comment: @gbronner  no no no!  You program an arduino to rotate the thermostat disk!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft can I program it with little robot arms to push buttons??

Comment: @DanTheMan only if you have a 3d printer to maker it with.